# Alternative for AWS Parameter Store on Digital Ocean

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-ocean, aws-parameter-store

I was using Parameter Store in AWS. Now I am migrating to Digital Ocean. Is there is any alternative for Parameter store in Digital Ocean ? Please help me out

Comment: @John Rotenstein Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a 3rd party service for this. You could checkout something like Doppler (link: https://www.doppler.com/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29888700)